# Сессия в React.js + Redux + JWT

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, jwt, react-router-dom

Всем привет. Делаю приложение на React.js, нужно сделать доступ к нему через авторизацию. Авторизацию сделал через JWT на бэке (laravel), но теперь возникла проблема с защитой всего приложения от доступа и сохранением сессии. После авторизации, сохраняю token JWT в localeStorage, но совершенно не могу понять, как при инициализации приложения, используя Redux, рендирить App, в случае если пользователь авторизован, и делать редирект на login, если нет. И помогите пожалуйста понять, как реализовать сессию через JWT и localStorage.

```js
const Content = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={"/"} render={props => <Empty {...props}/>}/>
                <Route component={NotFound}/>
            </Switch>
        </>
    )
};

const Login = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <AuthPage/>
            <Redirect to={'/login'}/>
        </>
    )
};

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <MainProvider>
                <div className={"app-wrapper"}>
                    {console.log(this.props.session())}
                    <Router path={'/'} render={() => (
                        this.props.session() ? (
                            <Content/>
                        ) : (
                            <Login/>
                        )
                    )}>
                    </Router>
                </div>
            </MainProvider>
        );
    }
}
```

this.props.session() это action, который получает профиль пользователя, и в случае успеха, помимо dispatch, возвращает также true.

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае я делал следующим образом:

При входе в приложение брал `JWT` из `localStorage`.

- Если `токена` нет - однозначно редирект на `login`.
- Если `токен` есть, я делал запрос к какому-то методу бэкенда (который требует `JWT`)

  а) если сервер ответил `200` - значит токен не протух и с ним можно дальше работать

  б) если сервер ответил `4xx` ошибкой (обычно `401` или `403`), то редирект на `login`

Comment: Слушай, а как ты делал проверку? У меня сейчас такая проблема, что при обращении к API, через Redux, соответственно происходит рендер, и всё по кругу. Посмотри пожалуйста на тот код, который я добавлю, что я делаю не так?(

Comment: у тебя внутри рендера есть <Redirect to={'/login'}/> поэтому происходит ререндер бесконечный

Comment: редирект в твоем случае надо делать где нибудь в componentDidMount